# Remote enable xdebug in PHPStorm for console scripts

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

How can I use xdebug on console scripts with PHPStorm 9 without having to enable `xdebug.remote_autostart`?

I've found that if I have `xdebug.remote_autostart` enabled, it hangs certain console scripts trying to do a DNS lookup.

I'm connecting to a vagrant box.

Here is my current Xdebug config:

```
zend_extension = xdebug.so
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 10
xdebug.default_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.10.1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.collect_return = 1
xdebug.collect_params = 10
xdebug.show_mem_delta = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/home/vagrant/Projects/xdebug_profiler"
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "/home/vagrant/Projects/xdebug_traces"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.trace_enable = 1
```

Comment: You have `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` which 1) overrides your `xdebug.remote_host` and 2) could the the reason for your extra DNS lookup. Try without it. Other than that -- you can place `xdebug_break();` in your PHP script to trigger breakpoints programatically (obviously, it will be triggering it all the time, so only keep it there if needed).

Comment: Yes, I figured that is why I'm getting the extra DNS lookup. I'd like to be able to have PHPStorm interact with Xdebug data without having to have `remote_autostart` on and without having to alter the code given I am sometimes connecting to debug a truly remote server that is only changed by pulling a repo. Any idea how I can use the native break points in PHPStorm without that option?

Comment: SSH. PhpStorm can execute and initiate debugging of your remote CLI scripts over SSH (the easiest way). Otherwise ... only by some "magic" (special environment variables that you have to set before debugging so that xdebug sees them -- just like POST/GET/COOKIE param for web request bu for CLI it should be slightly different) or by adding all necessary params when actually executing CLI script (`-d` option of php executable).

Comment: So what options do I enable in PHPStorm to cause initiation of an SSH connection specifically in concert with Xdebug monitoring?

Comment: It's all in official manuals. [This one](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Remote+debugging+in+PhpStorm+via+SSH+tunnel) about debugging over SSH